# Old sessions not deleted in Joomla session table

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I am running Joomla 3.8.6. Number of entries in session table is excess of 25k. But there are only a dozen users online. What's happening?

Today is June 19. I have registered user sessions that are 3 days old in the table. I have guest sessions as old as April 2 in the table.

This was not the case in an older version of Joomla. On May 20, I upgraded to Joomla 3.8.6. I have using Database for managing sessions. Expiry is set to 60 minutes.

**Edit (28 June), adding more details**

Session settings (configuration.php):

```
public $lifetime = '60';
public $session_handler = 'database';
public $shared_session = '0';
```

Plugin (from database):

```
INSERT INTO `fkd5g_extensions` (`extension_id`, `package_id`, `name`, `type`, `element`, `folder`, `client_id`, `enabled`, `access`, `protected`, `manifest_cache`, `params`, `custom_data`, `system_data`, `checked_out`, `checked_out_time`, `ordering`, `state`) VALUES
(480, 0, 'plg_system_sessiongc', 'plugin', 'sessiongc', 'system', 0, 0, 1, 0, '{"name":"plg_system_sessiongc","type":"plugin","creationDate":"February 2018","author":"Joomla! Project","copyright":"Copyright (C) 2005 - 2018 Open Source Matters. All rights reserved.","authorEmail":"admin@joomla.org","authorUrl":"www.joomla.org","version":"3.8.6","description":"PLG_SYSTEM_SESSIONGC_XML_DESCRIPTION","group":"","filename":"sessiongc"}', '', '', '', 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, 0);
```

Comment: sessiongc is not enabled and this the new default Joomla! setting.

Comment: You may like to try Joomla StackExchange for joomla support.  https://joomla.stackexchange.com/